# PHP Regex to get value after and before hyphen ( - )

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying to implement a PHP regex to get two numeric values: one before the dash "-" symbol and the other one after the symbol.

Let's say I have the range 320-420

I know I can use

`preg-match("/[^-]+$/", "320-420")`

But the regex I have only considers the number **after the symbol** and also I need to save the two numbers (320 and 420) in two variables, that the functions doesn't do.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: If this is EXACTLY what you need to do, you can make life a little easier with `$matches = explode('-', "320-420");` I personally would mix it with list like `list($a, $b) = explode('-', "320-420");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
preg_match('/(\d+)\-(\d+)/', '320-420', $matches)
```

But in my opinion the best solution:

```
list ($one, $two) = explode('-', '320-420');
```

Comment: I implemented the solution you suggested. It works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you have only `number-number` then using `explode()` as suggested by some people is best approach.

But suppose if you have string like this:

> Range of speed should be 30-50 km per hour.

In such cases RegEx should be used to match string.

Using simple regex like this `(\d+)-(\d+)` will capture both values in `capturing groups`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dW4qJ5/1)**